# Specify sort value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springdoc

I search a way for a spring boot 3 application to specify with spring doc the value of the sort who are allowed.

I tried that without success

```
@ParameterObject @PageableDefault(direction = Sort.Direction.ASC, sort = "name")@Schema(allowableValues = {"name", "age"})  Pageable pageable)
```